# Android ExpandableListView makes application to crash

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have been adding an ExpandableListView to my application following this tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Now when following this and I run the application it crashes.

Here is my code in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager viewpager;
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    PagerAdapter padapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewpager.setAdapter(padapter);

    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    prepareListData();
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

}

private void prepareListData(){
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
    top250.add("250");

    List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
    test.add("Din mamma");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), test);
}

}
```

These are the errors that don't tell me so much just that there is a problem on this rows:

```
at com.hoyer_group.hoyer.MainActivity.prepareListData(MainActivity.java:53)
at com.hoyer_group.hoyer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
```

Row 37 is:

```
prepareListData();
```

Row 53 is:

```
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250);
```

Hope for some clarity in this. 
Thanks.

Comment: can you give the type of error? maybe `NullPointerException` or something like that?

Comment: Here is what I get in the logcat:

06-01 22:47:05.786  28739-28739/com.hoyer_group.hoyer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hoyer_group.hoyer, PID: 28739
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hoyer_group.hoyer/com.hoyer_group.hoyer.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)

Answer (score 0):

`listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250);`

Your listDataHeader has no elements in it, but you're trying to access the first element.

Comment: I added listDataHeader.add("top250") and listDataHeader.add("test") in the prepareListData and now I am getting error: "java.lang.NullPointerException", have looked in my custom adapter and does not return null anywhere what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your `listDataHeader` List is empty, so, if you try to `get` any value, it will get Nothing, so it is your error, there are no elements in the list

Comment: Have added items to my listDataHeader and now I get NullPointerException at line : "expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);"

Answer (score 0):

In

```
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250);
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), test);
```

You are trying to get data from `listDataHeader`, and in the code you show us you do not did `listDataHeader.put` anywhere.

So, the Logcat error make sense:

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

Which corresponds with `listDataHeader.get(0)`.